# Authenticate to an REST api from another REST api in Spring Security

Tags: spring, rest, authentication, spring-security, token

I've a question about how to design a security problem.

Actually, we have an API secured by Spring Security.
It's based on the simple UserDetails security pattern.

Now, we are developing another API, deployed on(in a near future) another domain, against another database but the authentication information will be the same as the first API.

So, I would like to know how to design the authentication in the model. Actually I was thinking of something like:
[image]

Can I have your advice on that design?

Another question is how to implement that in Spring Security, especially the store & validate token on **2nd API**?

Answer (score 1):

I'd extract the authentifaction part into an own api, which handles only the login and token generation. The token would be stored in TokenStore (i.e. ad atabase) and with it along i'd store the userdetails and whcih api he can use.
The browser sends the token with each request to your api 1 and api 2. They can the check the token against the TokenStore and then validate if the user has the right to access this api.

You could use spring-security-oauth2 for this, but had to tweak the tokengeneration workflow a bit. In this case your UI app will be the authorizaion server and generate the tokens transparently for a logged in user and give it to the part running in the browser. Your App in the browser would ne to send this token on each call to api 1 or 2. Api 1 and 2 would be different resourceserver, but check against the same tokenstore.

Comment: Thanks, I will investigate this.